# after succesfully running B.py python returns "python.exe: No module named A.B.py"

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, anaconda

1. I have the following folder structure

> root_folder\__init__.py #empty file
>
> root_folder\A\__init__.py #emptyfile
>
> root_folder\A\B.py

2. I am calling from inside root_folder:

> root_folder>python -m A.B.py
>
> ```
> Correct Python output[everything runs ok until the last line]
>
> C:\Anaconda2\python.exe: No module named A.B.py
> ```

My problem is with "python.exe: No module named A.B.py", I'm not sure why it is triggered, since the script executes correctly and how to get read of it.

Comment: `A.B` is the module name `A.B.py` isn't the file name. Just do `python -m A.B`

Comment: I feel stupid now! @Jean-François Fabre thank you, it worked !

Comment: I linked to the original question, great answers here, no need to write another lousy one :)